# Pointer to destroyed class invalidation

Tags: c++, object, pointers, memory-management

**I have an object that many pointers point to. They often try to access the data. However at some point this object might be destroyed. How do I efficiently update those pointers as soon as I destroy the object so they won't point to unallocated memory and cause undefined behaviour?**

My Idea was making a list of pointers that need to be updated to `nullptr`. This would be called in the destructor of the object. Ugly mess and a lot of work for every single thing that might be deallocated.

Maybe there is some use in those smart pointers for cases like these (never used them). How do C++ programmers handle stuff like that?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr, more particularly https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr/expired

Comment: How about reference counting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply need to use [std::shared_ptr](https://fr.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) and [std::weak_ptr](https://fr.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr).

`shared_ptr` are so smart that you won't need to delete them, they will get deleted when nobody references them anymore. Then, any `weak_ptr` related to this `shared_ptr` will sort of be informed and there's no risk for it to access unallocated memory.

When it needs it the `weak_ptr` will try to `lock()` and create a local `shared_ptr`. If the original `shared_ptr` was removed, `lock()` will fail to create the local `shared_ptr` and you will safely know the original pointer was deleted.

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>
#include <memory>

int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<int> pI( new int(3) );
    std::weak_ptr<int> wI( pI );

    {
        // check if weak_ptr still "points" to some valid data:
        std::shared_ptr<int> pICopy = wI.lock();
        assert( pICopy != NULL );
        std::cout << "pI still valid " << *pICopy << std::endl;
    }

    pI.reset(); // this is equivalent to regular delete with shared_ptr

    {
        // check if weak_ptr does not "point" to any valid data:
        std::shared_ptr<int> pICopy = wI.lock();
        assert( pICopy == NULL );
        std::cout << "pI not valid anyore" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is pretty much exactly what I wanted. Guess its time to learn a new Pointer System...

Answer (score 0):

> Ugly mess and a lot of work for every single thing that might be deallocated

Well don't do the cleanup in the destructor. Make a separate function and call it in destructor .You can call this common cleanup function from the destructors of other objects.